# How can I extract data from a string using another string as a template?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for an efficient way to generically extract data from a string using another string as a template. Pseudocode:

```
var mystring = "NET,1:1,0,ipv4,192.168.1.7,255.255.255.0,192.168.1.1";
var mytemplate = "NET,[address],[lock_state],[ip_type],[ip],[netmask],[gateway]";
var result = mysteryMethod(mystring,mytemplate);
result:
    {
      address: '1:1',
      lock_state: '0',
      ip_type: 'ipv4',
      ip: '192.168.1.7',
      netmask: '255.255.255.0',
      gateway: '192.168.1.1'
    }
```

There is a comma delimiter in this case but not all strings will be delimited or will have different delimiters. None of the strings to be parsed will contain brackets. Is this possible and/or wise to do  with regular expressions? Speed is crucial in this case. As always, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I get that delimiters could be different in the same string. But does the template have the same "delimiter configuration" of the input string?

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way you have specified it. If the string might not be delimited, then what is the correct output for mystring = "abc", mytemplate = "[x][y]"? It could be either x:ab y:c OR x:a y:bc. I think you need to better specify what it is that you want to achieve.

Comment: Might want to look at this implementation of scanf in Javascript for inspiration: http://phpjs.org/functions/sscanf:886

Comment: @VitoShadow - yes, the template will have the same configuration. it is basically a copy of everything that isn't the data. There will always be at least one positional clue so the minimum template in MikeL's example would be "[x]b[y]" or "a[x][y]" or "[x][y]c".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is at http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/Kxe6W/

```
var templatizedStringParser = function(myTemplate, myString) {

    var names = [];
    var parts = myTemplate.replace( /\[([^\]]+)]/g, function(str, name) {
        names.push(name);
        return "~";
    }).split("~");

    var parser = function(myString) {
        var result = {};
        remainder = myString;
        var i, len, index;
        for (i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
            remainder = remainder.substring(parts[i].length);
            index = remainder.indexOf(parts[i + 1]);
            result[names[i]] = remainder.substring(0, index);
            remainder = remainder.substring(index);
        }
        result[names[names.length - 1]] = remainder;
        return result;
    };

    return myString ? parser(myString) : parser;
};
```

You can use it like this

```
console.log(templatizedStringParser(myTemplate, myString));
```

or this:

```
var parser = templatizedStringParser(myTemplate);
console.log(parser(myString));
```

There is almost certainly some cruft in there as I did this in a hurry.  The use of the "~" might not work for you.  And there are likely other problems if you have boundary issues, but it might cover many cases.
​

Answer (score 1):

```
//This method obtains each lable in the template string
function getLables(patt, templateStr) {
    var i = 0;
    var tmp = patt.exec(templateStr);
    var lables = new Array();
    while(tmp) {
        lables[i] = new String(tmp).replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
        tmp = patt.exec(templateStr);
        ++i;
    }
    return lables;
}

function extract(_inputStr, _template) {
    //Supposing the start string in template is NET
    var startStr = "NET";
    var inputStr = _inputStr.replace(startStr, "");
    var template = "";

    //You can add a control on the correctness of the template
    if(_template.indexOf(startStr) != 0) {
        return false;
        //you could use a throw clausole, in order to use exceptions
    } else {
        template = _template.replace(startStr, "");
    }

    var patt = /\[[a-z | _]+\]/ig; //Pattern to recognize each [lable]
    var delim = template.replace(patt, "[]").split("[]"); //Delimiter list
    var lable = getLables(patt, template); //Lables list
    var result = new Object();

    var endIndex;
    for(var i=0; i<lable.length; ++i) {
        inputStr = inputStr.replace(delim[i], "");
        endIndex = inputStr.indexOf(delim[i+1]);

        if( (i+1) == lable.length ) {
            result[lable[i]] = inputStr.substring(0, inputStr.length);
        } else {
            result[lable[i]] = inputStr.substring(0, endIndex)
            inputStr = inputStr.replace(result[lable[i]], "");
        }

    }

    return result;
}
```

In this example:

```
var template = "NET???[one]/[two]";
var inputStr = "NET???test/8";

JSON.stringify(extract(inputStr, template));
```

The result is:

```
{
    "one":"test",
    "two":"8"
}
```