# How to go from DOM to variables via reverse templating?

Tags: javascript, templating

**(I've answered this below)** I'd like to know how I can produce an object such as `{ name: 'iLoch', message: 'Hello' }` given a DOM element, and the template that produced it. Here's an example:

DOM:

```
<div>iLoch says "Hello"</div>
```

Template:

```
<div>{{name}} says "{{message}}"</div>
```

And I want to produce that original object by "intersecting" the template with the actual DOM contents:

```
{ name: 'iLoch', message: 'Hello' }
```

Comment: You can use Regular Expressions to match your patterns.

Comment: This was the first thing I came up with too - but I'd prefer a library that'll do this in an obvious way.

Comment: I have removed the `mustache` tag, while I see the similarities of the `{{tagname}}` concept, it isn't related to mustache, which only takes a template to render to HTML not the reverse as you desire.

Comment: I have found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333168/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-string-using-another-string-as-a-template

Comment: Interesting Scott, checking it out now.

Comment: Thanks for that Scott, was able to fork it and write my own.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: This doesn't seem to work as expected yet.. I should have tested it with more than one instance that needed to be replaced. Will update when it works.**

**Edit 2: Here it is! Should work as I expected it to originally... http://jsfiddle.net/Yy2yJ/**

I've created a solution based on Scott's comment, which can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/faAsQ

I haven't tested this thoroughly enough to see if anything breaks it - but please comment here if this helped you or if you have improvements. Cheers!

```
var untemplate = function(template, html) {
    var names = [],
        obj = {},
        encodedHtml = escape(html);

    var templateRegex = new RegExp(escape(template).replace(/[\\\/\.\-\*]/g, function(match) {
            return '\\' + match;
    }).replace(/%7B%7B([^(?:%7B)]+?)%7D%7D/g, function(match, name) {
            names.push(name);
            return '(.*?)';
        }), 'g');

    encodedHtml.replace(templateRegex, function() {

        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length - 2; i++) {
            obj[names[i - 1]] = unescape(arguments[i]);
        }
    });

    return obj;
}

console.log(untemplate('<div id="test">{{name}}</div><a>{{desc}}</a><a>{{desc2}}</a>', document.getElementById('container').innerHTML));
```