# Extracting data from a string using a given format

Tags: javascript

as a python programmer that has recently moved to JS, I used a library called
'parse' https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse/1.8.0.
You supplied a template for a string, and the actual string and it would return the data you wanted. For example:

```
parse("It's {}, I love it!", "It's spam, I love it!")
```

would return `spam`.

I have been looking for a JS solution to this problem, And I cannot find any, apart from this:
[How can I extract data from a string using another string as a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333168/how-can-i-extract-data-from-a-string-using-another-string-as-a-template)

I have tried this out, but it has not worked very well.
Thank you in advance, GoldPython

Comment: Why does it work not well ? Show us what you tried

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want with Regular expressions

Comment: What about Regexp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by using RegExp.

First you need to escape characters that have a special meaning in RegExp:

```
var toMatch = "I don't understand it, but: It's spam, I love it! I really really love it!";
var pattern = "It's {}, I love {}!";

function pythonParse(pattern, toMatch, bShortest) {
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\\/g,"\\\\");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\^/g, "\\^");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\(/g, "\\(");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\)/g, "\\)");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\[/g, "\\[");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\]/g, "\\]");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\%/g, "\\%");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\?/g, "\\?");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\:/g, "\\:");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\//g, "\\/");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\*/g, "\\*");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\./g, "\\.");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\+/g, "\\+");
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\|/g, "\\|");

   var lazy = "";
   if(bShortest)
     lazy = "?";

   // Replace the parse pattern {} with (.*) regex pattern
   pattern = pattern.replace(/\{\}/g, "(.*" + lazy + ")");

   // Then you can use this pattern to retrieve the result
   var matches = toMatch.match(new RegExp(pattern));
   // Count results
   if(!matches)
     return "";
   if(matches.length > 2) {
     matches.shift();
     return matches;
   }
   else
     return matches[1];
}  

var result = pythonParse(pattern, toMatch, true);
console.log(result);
```

Please see a working example here: http://jsbin.com/vuluca/edit?js,console

EDITED to allow for lazy comparison using the optional `bShortest` boolean parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Already found a regex soloution, thanks anyway :)
http://regexr.com/3fnm2